# Как центрировать текст в QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qlayout, alignment

Начнём с того, что я только сегодня вообще узнал, что такое PyQt5, поэтому прошу всё объяснить простым и понятным языком. Спасибо.

Есть код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt
 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Записки')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))     

        # Вот ниже находится label, который нужно центрировать.
        lbl1 = QLabel('Привет! Что нового?', self)
        lbl1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter) #Попытка не удачная. Ничего не работает
        #lbl1.move(0, 0) #если раскоментировать, чуда не произойдёт

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self) # Бонусный вопрос: Как центрировать кнопку? :з
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.test)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(3, 15)
    
        self.show()

    def test(self):
        print('test удался')
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `lbl1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто. Вам надо изучить Класс `QLayout`, который  является базовым классом менеджеров геометрии.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt
 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Записки')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))     

        # Вот ниже находится label, который нужно центрировать.
        lbl1 = QLabel('Привет! Что нового?', self)
        lbl1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)                      #  (Qt.AlignVCenter)
#        #lbl1.move(0, 0) #если раскоментировать, чуда не произойдёт

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self) # Бонусный вопрос: Как центрировать кнопку? :з
        btn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.test)
#        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
#        btn.move(3, 15)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)                         # +++
        layout.addWidget(lbl1)                             # +++
        layout.addWidget(btn)                              # +++    
   
#        self.show()

    def test(self):
        print('test удался')
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()                                              # +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понял. А по какой логике он туда устанавливается? И как центрировать его не по центру окна, а только по горизонтали? По вертикали он должен находится вверху.

Comment: @Electroplayer  замените `lbl1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)`  на `lbl1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)`

Comment: @Electroplayer  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Electroplayer пожалуйста